# Setting text to text box on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I cant get the idea, how do I set text to text box on button click.
This is my markup :

Picture :
[image]

Markup:

```
 <div id="deploymentsGrid">
    @if (db.CatalogCircumstances.Any())

    {
        @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "table",
        headerStyle: "table_HeaderStyle",
        footerStyle: "table_PagerStyle",
        rowStyle: "table_RowStyle",
        alternatingRowStyle: "table_AlternatingRowStyle",
        selectedRowStyle: "table_SelectedRowStyle",
        columns: grid.Columns(

            grid.Column("Nr", @Resources.Localization.nr, format: @<text>
                @{ row = row + 1;} @item.Nr
            </text>, style: "p13"),

            grid.Column("Description", @Resources.Localization.description, format: @<text>
                        @{ row = row + 1;} @item.Description
            </text>, style: "width:250px"),


            grid.Column("", "", format: @<text>
                                <input id="select_bttn" style="width:78px" type="submit" value=@Resources.Localization.select />
            </text>)
                )
            )
    }
    <br />
</div>




<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddCircumstanceToList", "Health", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmployeeId)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nr, Model.Nr, new { style = "width:100px" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, Model.Description, new { style = "width:450px" })
        <br />
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Start_date)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Start_date, new { id = "datepicker5" })
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.End_date)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.End_date, new { id = "datepicker4" })

            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Localization.save" style="width:78px" />
    }
    <button id="closer">@Resources.Localization.back</button>
</div>
```

And i`d like when clicking on 'select-bttn' text was set to textboxes(inside beginform) and then posted to an action on save button click.

Comment: I have tried to make upper part in beginform, and get new model with new data, and then send this model to lower part, setting textbox values. But it refreshes the page, what I don`t like to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly replace your `select_bttn` with this:

```
<input id="select_bttn" class="select_bttn" style="width:78px" type="button" value="OK" data-nr="@item.Nr" data-description="@item.Description" />
```

Secondly add a jQuery function which will get the `Nr` and `Description` properties of the clicked row and set the values of the two textboxes:

```
$(function () {
    $(".select_bttn").click(function () {
        var nr = $(this).data('nr');
        var description = $(this).data('description');

        var message = "You clicked on.Nr - " + nr + ".Description - " + description + ".";
        alert(message);

        $("#Nr").val(nr);
        $("#Description").val(description);
    });
});
```

**Output:**

[image: Button click event in MVC WebGrid]

Comment: So, i ve done both steps, alert shows correct values, but they are not set to textboxes.

Comment: Had to change textbox ids because i had already had Nr and description elements above.

Comment: So, now i have got an issue, i have kind a strange paging (with usual, pop up was closed) it is calling the method which returns partial view again. So on the first page script works fine, but when i choose second one, script just stops working, but others (datepicker script for example) are still working. How can i fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

1 Add id to your Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(     
         "AddCircumstanceToList", "Health", FormMethod.Post, 
         new { id = "myForm" }))}
```

2 Add this jquery

```
$( "#select_bttn" ).click(function() { 
    $("#Description").val("hello world");
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Had to tell from the question, but this part "*i`d like when clicking on 'select-bttn' text was set to textboxes(inside beginform) and then posted to an action on save button click.*" implies there are **two** buttons, one to set the text and the *other* to submit.  This sets the text and submits on one button.

Comment: No need to add an ID, you can use `$("form").submit()`